# No me funciona correctamente la función .find(). ¿Alguna idea?

Tags: javascript, array, formularios, objeto, método

Estoy intentando utilizar el método .find(), que me encuentre un dato específico de un array, nutrido de un formulario.
Pero cuando utilizo el método find de javascript, solo comprueba, pero se queda en bucle.
Dejo el código utilizado, a ver si ven el error en la función dniComprueba(){}

Por mozzila, comenta que el método find, funciona muy bien, pero cuando el array es mas sencillo, pero cuando utilizo un array que contiene mas de una variable, es cuando se tranca.

Código de javascript que estoy utilizando.

```js
baseDatos = [];

function ingresa() {

    function Persona(nombre, dni, descripcion) {
        this.nombre; 
        this.dni;  
        this.descripcion;
    }


    var nombrePrueba = document.getElementById("nombre").value; 
    var dniPrueba = document.getElementById("dni").value;
    var descripcionPrueba = document.getElementById("descripcion").value;

    nuevoUsuario = new Persona(nombrePrueba, dniPrueba, descripcionPrueba);



    
    if (nombrePrueba == "", dniPrueba == "", descripcionPrueba == "") {

        alert("Completa tus datos, gracias.");

       
    } else if (!dniComprueba(dniPrueba)) {
       baseDatos.push(nuevoUsuario);


  document.getElementById("datos").innerHTML += // recuerda usar += ya que sino, no agrega nada más al array 
            '<td>' + nombrePrueba + '</td>' + '        ' +
            '<td>' + dniPrueba + '</td>' + '        ' +
            '<td>' + descripcionPrueba + '</td>' + '        ' +
            '<input type="button" value="Borrar" onclick="">' + '<br>';
       
    } else {
        
        alert("Ya existe el dni");
    }
}

function dniComprueba(dniPrueba) { 

 var compruebaDni = baseDatos.find(baseDatos => nuevoUsuario === nuevoUsuario);
 
 if (compruebaDni) {
        return true; 
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
   
cÓDIGO EN HTML, que utilizo, formulario básico, que se encarga de cargar datos.

> Cita en bloque
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PRUEBA </title>
    <script src="form6_3Arrays.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Base de datos prueba 5</h1>

   
    <form value="">

       
        <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" autofocus>
        <input type="text" id="dni" placeholder="dni">
        <input type="text" id="descripcion" placeholder="Descripcion">
        <input type="button" value="Agregar" onclick="ingresa()">


    </form>
    <div id="datos"> </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta? ¿Cómo gestionas la persistencia? ¿Los datos se quedan en memoria?

Comment: Saber cómo verificar si ya existe un dato específico, para que me deje agregar o me avise de que ya existe en base de datos ese usuario. Y la segunda parte, una vez que deje agregar el usuario en el array, que el botón eliminar, me permita eliminar ese usuario en específico y que en el html sólo se borre esa parte y no se me borre todo el contenido. // ¿ Qué es la persistencia? // Los datos los almaceno hasta refrescar la página web. Sólo estoy utilizando javascript, no apis, no php.// Muchas gracias

Comment: En js tienes un metodo que es find(). Como guardas los datos en un array, solo tendrias que buscar con find si el usuario esta dentro del array. Te dejo un enlace donde puedes consultarlo.https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Muchas gracias @cupax64. Lo voy a revisar y comento en caso de no conseguirlo.

Comment: @cupax64 he modificado el código, cuando utilizo array único, me funciona correctamente, pero ahora que utilizo array global, que contiene 3 variables, y trato que me busque un valor específico, lo ejecuta, lo reconoce, pero no me agrega más datos. Me cae en ELSE, repetitivo. Espero puedas encontrar el error. Gracias